# How can I animate the removal or addition of elements from a `React-Virtualized` list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-virtualized

It seems React-Virtualized does not support animations out of the box, but is it possible (and reasonable?) to use [`ReactCSSTransitionGroup`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) to implement transitions?

In my case I'd like to do a remove animation (e.g., fade opacity or shrink height) transition on an element in a virtualized list.

Comment: Being that are in control of the rendered element, I don't see why using transitions should be an issue (as long as your not animating height/width and using CellMeasurer). Would love to see what you have out together!

Comment: @mauron85 answer points in a very nice direction but as this codepen: http://codepen.io/thomasmery/pen/evrqNy shows
it won't work when removing a row (expected behaviour is here: http://codepen.io/thomasmery/pen/vxrLqG) - hope someone can help understand why it behaves differently with RV